# AWS Lambda: Is there a benefit to using an async handler function for the Node runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I'm creating an AWS SAM application using Node.js Lambda functions. The default template has an async handler function:

```js
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  // ...
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ hello: "world" })
  };
};
```

Is there any benefit to having this handler function be `async` vs `sync`, since my understanding is each time a Lambda function is invoked it runs separately from other instances?

Comment: `async` allows you to use `await` in the function body. If you're not using `await`, then there is very little reason to use `async`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AWS Lambda handles synchronous functions and asynchronous functions as well. `async` means two things:

- The function returns a `Promise`
- You are able to use `await` inside it

AWS Lambda happens to understand Promises as return value, thats why `async` functions work as well. So if you need `await` just go for `async`.

You could also not declare the function as `async` and `return` a `Promise` (or chain of Promises)

Comment: Is there a diff between returning a Promise with and without the async keyword in the function header?

Comment: No there isn't. It's just a matter of code style

Comment: thx for noting that async function handler means it should return a promise

Answer (score 1):

use async handler function if you want to use return and throw to send a response or error respectively from your function handler.

you can use non-async handler but it only terminates the function execution when the event loop is empty or the function times out.

ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

Comment: I do not get your point. "Async" refers to the fact that you have code inside the function that needs to run async.